# MySql autoincrement counter resetting after server restart

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, auto-increment

I need a way to keep auto-increment counter between mysql service restart.

As docs states by default after restart mysql autoincrement counter start from max(id)+1. How can I keep the last autoincrement value?

This is a big problem for me. I'm using envers to keep entities audits. I get as many errors as many "last rows" I delete.

Suppose I'm starting insert data into an empty table. Suppose to insert 10 rows. Then suppose to delete the last 8. In my table I will have as result 2 entities, with id 1 and 2 respectively. In the audit table I will have all 10 entities, with id from 1 to 10: entities with id from 3 to 10 will have 2 action: create action and delete action.

auto-increment counter is now setted to 11 in main table. Restarting mysql service auto-increment counter goes to 3. So if I insert a new entity, it will be saved with id 3. But in audit table there is already an entity with id = 3. That entity is already marked as created and deleted. It result in an assertion failure during update /delete action because envers cannot handle this inconsistent state.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## MySQL fix

After [14.5 years this is fixed in MySQL version 8.0](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=199)

> [6 Oct 16:40] Daniel Price Posted by developer: Fixed in 8.0.0 by [WL#6204.](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=6204)

- [**WL#6204**: *InnoDB persistent max value for autoinc columns*](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=6204)

## MariaDB fix

Also this was [MariaDB 10.2.4 released on July 12, 2017](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-1027-release-notes/)

- [**MDEV-6076** *Persistent AUTO_INCREMENT for InnoDB*](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-6076).

I found out this change was finally added on the 2ndquadrant blog,

- [*Why PostgreSQL is better than MySQL*](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-better-mysql-1/)

Answer (score 1):

If your auto-increments do have a meaning outside of an arbitrary indentifier, maybe they shouldn't be `auto_increment`s, but simple int or bigint unsigned.

You can drop the auto_increment particle and just insert max(id)+1, but **that would create you all sorts of concurrency problems** (that the auto_increment solves for you automatically).

**You could store the auto_increment on a separate table** or table comment, and edit the table's auto_increment or insert auto_increment value - 1 and then delete it, depending on the ENGINE. But again, I would think twice why you want this before implementing it. Remember that gaps can be produced at any time.

**EDIT:** that is reasonable- I would recommend not deleting rows (mark them as "deleted=true") or following the advice above: on start, execute a query to check that your auto_increment (`SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema='database' AND table_name='table'`) is larger than `max(audited_id)` and perform a fake insert. You can put that logic with [`--init-file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file) or on a trigger, [as seen on this comment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#c12158).